# Advice for planning a weekly schedule

Tags: gym

My current weight is 86 kg, I have lost already 20 kg since February this year using water fasting and intermittent fasting. Now I have been on a pause from the water fast for two months, doing just 20:4 fasting. My plan is to go to 80 kg (maybe 78 kg), also I have slight problem loosing my belly fat, even if I  cut lot's of crap food and added sugar. I am 198 cm long, 36 years.

My plan is as follows:
Mon (upper body, abs), Wed (lower body, abs), Fri (full body)
Tue (running 5km), Thu (running 5km), Sat (running 10km)

And the question is if it's good to have, as an extra, pushups, situps and let's say planks daily at 9AM (gym sessions are from 5PM to 7PM), because I work at home and I sit most of the day. Or will it be too much for myself?

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your only goal is weight loss it doesn't matter what you do for exercise, so we cannot tell you what to do with your exercise without knowing what your goals are for it. Are you trying to get stronger by some metric? Trying to run a 5k in a certain time?

Comment: I think this question is far too broad to be able to give any answer other than "hire a professional coach to write a program for you". Also, if the large volume of ab training that you're doing is in the hope of burning belly fat, that won't work. Search this site for "belly fat" to see existing explanations of why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks for suggesting!